Handling Synchronous Socket Reads and Asynchronous Events in Python
As an educational project, I'm working on a Python application that involves multiple threads, each blocked on a synchronous socket read operation. I need these threads to also respond to two types of events: individual thread-specific events and broadcast events that all threads should respond to. The challenge is to handle these events without interrupting the blocking read on the socket.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

Each thread is continuously reading from its own dedicated socket.
I need each thread to handle "personal" events and a "broadcast" event. The broadcast event should be received by all threads simultaneously without any one of them missing it due to others reading it first.

The solution needs to ensure that while a thread is blocked on a socket read, it can still react to the broadcast events. I've considered using select to monitor the sockets and other descriptors, but I'm unsure how to implement the broadcast mechanism properly. Here's the conceptual approach I've thought about:

Use os.pipe() to create communication channels for the personal and broadcast events.
Use select.select() to wait on the sockets and these pipes simultaneously.

However, I'm struggling with the scenario where the broadcast event must be handled by all threads without any thread missing it because another has already read it. Here's a rough sketch of what I'm thinking:
import select
import socket
import os
import threading

# Setup for sockets and pipes

def thread_function(sock, rfd):
    while True:
        readable, _, _ = select.select([sock, rfd], [], [])
        for r in readable:
            if r == sock:
                data = sock.recv(1024)  # Handle socket data
            elif r == rfd:
                os.read(rfd, 1024)  # Handle event

# Threads setup and event handling logic here

My questions are:

How can I implement a broadcast event mechanism that ensures all threads receive the event without one consuming it before the others?
Is there a better way to structure this system to handle both dedicated and broadcast events while keeping the socket read operations blocking?

Any insights, suggestions, or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You should use asyncio to run an eventloop on each thread, it is implemented on top of select but it is cross-platform, and you can use loop.call_soon_threadsafe to run a function on that thread, and to submit a coroutine to the eventloop you need to use loop.create_task in the same thread running the eventloop, because the eventloop is not threadsafe.
working with sockets and threads directly is a bit messy, but here is an example.
import asyncio
import threading
import time
import socket

class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = None
        self.sock = None

    async def read_socket(self, address):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        await self.loop.sock_connect(self.sock, address)
        result = await self.loop.sock_recv(self.sock, 1024)
        print(result)

    def run(self, address):
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.read_socket(address))

    async def notification(self):
        print("notified!")

address = ('127.0.0.1', 6767)

workers = []
for i in range(2):
    worker = Worker()
    workers.append(worker)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker.run, args=(address,))
    thread.start()

time.sleep(0.1)  # wait for worker startup, maybe use threading.Event here

for worker in workers:
    worker.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(lambda: worker.loop.create_task(worker.notification()))

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(address)
s.listen(5)
for i in range(2):
    conn, address = s.accept()
    conn.send(b"data")

notified!
notified!
b'data'
b'data'

You have loop.is_running() to check if a worker is currently running, and you can use loop.stop() to forcefully stop it, and inside this coroutine you can have it await on multiple sockets or file descriptors.
At this point you can run them all in one eventloop on the main thread ... but you could have a reason to use a thread for each connection, there are definitely better ways to do this.

yes... as a learning project I will have to do the same thing also using asyncio, but first I have to complete other tasks including this one, using thread and select

@mastupristi without asyncio you need each thread to have its own queue.Queue and listen on a notification file descriptor, and whenever it is pinged on that file descriptor it  would read the actual event from the queue, that's less error prone, and likely faster than using OS pipes, a broadcast notification would just put messages on each and every queue, and notify each and every fd, you don't want to be sharing any file descriptors or queues, as you'd just be putting yourself on the mercy of the OS.

what do you mean by "notification file descriptor" or "ping a file descriptor"?

@mastupristi you can create a file descriptor whose only purpose is to emit events that interrupt select, on linux this is done by os.eventfd, while on windows there is CreateEvent, asyncio abstracts the differences, and i would stick to linux only for your educational implementation, each thread will have its own fd and for other threads to send notifications it would write to it, then you can read it from that thread, then read from the queue.

I would think a threading.Barrier instance passed to  worker.run would be more suitable than a threading.Event instance if you want to remove the call to time.sleep(0.1).
